# Removing an item from .loc based on a conditional statement

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame which I am trying to remove items from, based on the value.

```
for i in range (1, len(df['column1'])):
    if df['column1'].iloc[i][0] < 2.5:
        del df['column1'].iloc[i]
```

Received error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-8b343357b723> in <module>()
     16 for i in range (1, len(df_agg2['water_amount']-1)):
     17     if df_agg2['water_amount'].iloc[i][0] < 2.5:
---> 18         del df_agg2['water_amount'].iloc[i]

AttributeError: __delitem__
```

For example:

```
df['column1'].iloc[1]
```

returns:

```
sum    1.422883
Name: 4, dtype: float64
```

and,

```
df['column1'].iloc[1][0]
```

returns:

```
1.4228829999999981
```

How can I avoid the AttributeError that I am getting above, in order to remove the item if it is less than 2.5?

Comment: Do you want to drop the whole rows where `column1` is < 2.5?

Comment: Can you post sample data for the dataframe df ?

Comment: @languitar Yes, that's my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove rows from a frame based on a column, you can just select the inverse like so:

```
In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['test', 'this', 'not'], 'column1': [13, 0.2, 10]})

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
   column1   foo
0     13.0  test
1      0.2  this
2     10.0   not

In [9]: df[df.column1 >= 2.5]
Out[9]:
   column1   foo
0     13.0  test
2     10.0   not
```

Answer (score 1):

You question is not clear, assuming that you need to remove the cell when it is less than 2.5. Just remember that you can not actually remove the cell, instead replace that cell with np.Nan

```
df.ix[df.column1 <2.5, 'column1'] = np.NaN
```

it is also possible to remove entire row if the value is less than 2.5

```
print df[df.joint1_pt >2.5]
```